# Count number of files with certain string in it [PHP]

Tags: php

I have a directory with subdirectories in it, I am trying to loop over all of them and also loop on the filenames to count how many time there is a string inside it.

**inside of a subdirectory:** (i get this output)

../convo/96376/96376-**200**-2019-03-28-16-15-49.wav

../convo/96376/96376-**200**-2019-04-01-11-46-52.wav

../convo/96376/96376-**200**-2019-04-01-11-47-27.wav

../convo/96376/96376-**263**-2020-01-06-09-40-24.wav

../convo/96376/96376-**263**-2020-01-06-10-08-16.wav

Here I need to count how many files have **(200)** or **(263)** to make a report.

I already isolated the number i need and stored it in a variable ($poste). I just don't know how I am supposed to make a count here since i have nothing to compare. Here is what i got so far

200 and 263 are not hardcoded (I will never know the numbers in advance) and there could be alot more to count

```
$directory = '../convo/';
$count = 0;

$subDirectories = scandir($directory);

unset($subDirectories[0]);
unset($subDirectories[1]);

foreach ($subDirectories as $subDirectory) {
    echo '<h2>' . $subDirectory . '</h2>';

    foreach (glob($directory . $subDirectory . '/*') as $file) {

        $poste_explode = explode('-', $file);
        $poste = $poste_explode[1];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just need the count for 200 & 263, try this:

```
$directory = '../convo/';
$count = 0;

$subDirectories = scandir($directory);

unset($subDirectories[0]);
unset($subDirectories[1]);

foreach ($subDirectories as $subDirectory) {
    echo '<h2>' . $subDirectory . '</h2>';

    foreach (glob($directory . $subDirectory . '/*') as $file) {

        $poste_explode = explode('-', $file);
        $poste = $poste_explode[1];

        if (in_array($poste,["200","263"])) {
            $count++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a test for the values and put a counter here:

```
$posteCounter = 0;
foreach (glob($directory . $subDirectory . '/*') as $file) {

    $poste_explode = explode('-', $file);
    $poste = $poste_explode[1];
    if(200 == $poste || 263 == $poste) {
        $posteCounter++;
    }
```

Or you could count each one so that you have separate values which can be totaled:

```
//set variables outside the loop to hold the values
$_200 = 0;
$_263 = 0;

if(200 == $poste) {
    $_200++;
} elseif (263 == $poste) {
    $_263++;
}
```

**EDIT** Based on comments provided by the OP:

In order to find all of the poste values and then count you will have to loop twice through your directory. The first loop will build an array:

```
foreach(glob($directory . $subDirectory . '/*') as $file) {

    $poste_explode = explode('-', $file);
    $postes[] = $poste_explode[1]; // create and populate $postes array

}
```

Now you can loop through the `$postes` array and count files with those values, setting up a variable variable (there are likely better ways, but a lack of coffee isn't bringing them to mind) for each of the poste numbers. Here is an [EXAMPLE of an experiment in progress](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7a29131dc13fa6bd183430f61947d784846791e1)

```
$filenames = ['a-2-foo', 'b-2-bar', 'c-3-glorp'];

foreach($filenames as $filename){
    $poste_explode = explode('-', $filename);
    $postes[] = $poste_explode[1];
    if(!isset(${'poste_' . $poste_explode[1]})){
        ${'poste_' . $poste_explode[1]} = 0; // set up variable variable
    }
}

var_dump( get_defined_vars() );


print_r($postes);

foreach($postes as $poste){
    echo $poste . "\n";
    foreach($filenames as $filename){
        $poste_explode = explode('-', $filename);
        if($poste == $poste_explode[1]){
            echo ${'poste_' . $poste} . "\n";
            ${'poste_' . $poste}++; // variable variable
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: my only problem is that i don't know how many variables I have to set, its going to change everytime

Comment: You didn't state that in your original issue, that would take a completely different set of logic and would probably require an array of the variables to achieve.

Comment: Then you need to tell us how you plan to supply/determine the variables. The added information completely changes your question.

Comment: I need to count number of times there is a file with the same "poste" in each subdirectory, not knowing the poste in advance. It is possible?

Comment: Yes - for each directory you scan check an array of the poste's. If the poste is not there it gets added to the array. Then you can check the poste number and increment it. The logic is way different as you would build the array first, the loop through the array to find each file with that poste to accumulate the account.

Comment: I did that and it worked, thank you very much ! @Jay

Comment: [completed experiment](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cdbf4d63cf1bf7c541165343564a771ad03f5b4a) is a much more complete set of code which removes a filename from the array once it has been counted to avoid over-counting the files.